# Storing objects and distrubuting them dynamically

Tags: c#, reflection, abstract

I'm building a small app to somehow improve work with microcontrollers. Thus, I want to have a library of supported ones stored somewhere. I want each node to describe the constraints, (options) to manipulate, like GPIOs or interrupts. For example: STM8s which is inherited from Device class and has to describe how many GPIO it has, under what register, a flag maybe to mark it as analog/digital. Is there a way to do something like a class with abstract properties which have to be populated in its instances? Second questions is how to pass it to host application - I know I have to use Reflection class, but how to import already instatiated class to collection from assembly?

Hope it's clear ;)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for an IOC container.
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

I personally use Unity with C# : http://unity.codeplex.com/